# не работает jQuery ajax запрос

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

установил wampserver.
Пытаюсь реализовать простейший запрос, но не получаю ответ сервера. Файлы находятся в одной папке

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

</head>

<body>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

$.post('work.php', { value1 : '1', value2 : '2' }, function(data){ alert('Answer: '+data); });

});
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

work.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['value1'], $_POST['value2'])){ 

    $return = ''; 

    if($_POST['value1'] < $_POST['value2']){ 
        $return = 'Value1 < Value2'; 
    } 
    elseif($_POST['value1'] > $_POST['value2']){ 
        $return = 'Value1 > Value2'; 
    } 
    else{ 
        $return = 'Value1 = Value2'; 
    } 

    echo $return; 
} 
else{ 
    echo 'Some Error!'; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Есть метки [php], [wamp] и [wamp-server] может лучше использовать их вместо [jquery], [ajax], [post]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое точно заработает если не работает значит проблема с сервером

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickButtonPath").bind("click", function show() {
           var  path = $("#path").val();
           var id = $("#clickButtonPath").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "script.php",  
                data: {
                      path: path, 
                      id: id},  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                }    
                }  
            });  
        });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="path">
<button type="button" id="clickButtonPath" value="ok">ok</button>
</form>
```

```html
<?php
echo $_POST["path"];
```